# Can someone help me optimizing this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables `A, B, C`.
i have to take SName from `A` where `rollNumber = 11`
and `Bname` from `B` where `BCode = 10`
and then `select C.SName,C.Bname, C.ID from C where SName = "one obtained from A table" and BName = "one obtained from B table"`

I have written this query:

```
select C.SName, C.Bname, ID 
from A,B,C 
where B.Bname = C.Bname and A.SName = C.SName and 
      A.rollNumber='11' and B.Bcode='10';
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to have optimized in this query?
can you give an example on how the table content looks like?

Comment: start using ANSI JOINS....

Comment: Create some indexes, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT C.SName, C.BName, C.ID
FROM C
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM A WHERE rollNumber='11') as t1
ON t1.SName = C.SName
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B WHERE Bcode='10') as t2
ON t2.BName = C.Bname;
```

One optimization you can do is filter to a smaller temp table first before you perform join. This will result in much lesser rows in JOIN. Another optimization will be indexing all the columns involved in JOIN...ON clause and WHERE clause.

Comment: "One optimization you can do is filter to a smaller temp table first before you perform join" - huh? That doesn't sound right....

Comment: @MitchWheat `(SELECT * FROM A WHERE rollNumber='11')` Instead of joining the entire table A then only filter by `WHERE rollNumber='11'` at the end, you are joining with a temp table containing only rows with rollNumber='11'.

Comment: There is no optimization in this syntax, if the optimizer is smart enough it will join the whole table and use indexes.

Comment: @lamandy: your understanding of how an optimiser and joins work is a little flawed.

Comment: @MtwStart it's more that if the optimizer is smart enough, Lamandy's reworked query and the OPs original query should produce the same execution plan.

Comment: I suppose since the OP didn't provide any details, we might try randomly moving syntax around like this in the hope that something happens to work differently. The optimiser will generally merge and unnest anyway, though, so I wouldn't expect this to make any difference. Also there is no "temp table" in the query (probably just as well) - I'm not sure if that comment was meant to relate to the proposed version or was just another thing to try (in which case, how?)